# Can a non-EU national apply for a work permit from within Germany on business visa?

Tags: visa, germany

Currently, I'm in a hiring process of a company in Germany as a front-end developer, which is related to software development. The company's hiring process involves visiting the office for a few days and, during the visit, arriving at a decision on a job offer. The company has put me in contact with an agent who is handling the visa process. For the visit to the company's office, the agent registered an appointment for business visa two weeks ago. The appointment is scheduled in the second week of September. Additionally, there will be a wait of about 2 weeks to actually get the visa after the appointment.

Yesterday, the agent also registered an appointment for a work visa, because the queue is long and could result in a long wait in case of a job offer by the company.

My question: If on the visit, the company extends a job offer and I sign a contract while still being in Germany, can't I apply for a work permit and temporary residence permit from within Germany and wait for them to get approved? Is the exit and re-entry with a work visa even necessary?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible.  The *Aufenthaltsverordnung* says, [at section 39](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__39.html):

> Über die im Aufenthaltsgesetz geregelten Fälle hinaus kann ein Ausländer einen Aufenthaltstitel im Bundesgebiet einholen oder verlängern lassen, wenn
>
> ...
>
> er...ein gültiges Schengen-Visum für kurzfristige Aufenthalte (§ 6 Absatz 1 Nummer 1 des Aufenthaltsgesetzes) besitzt, sofern die Voraussetzungen eines Anspruchs auf Erteilung eines Aufenthaltstitels nach der Einreise entstanden sind, es sei denn, es handelt sich um einen Anspruch nach den §§ 16, 17b oder 18d des Aufenthaltsgesetzes,
>
> ...

Translation:

> In addition to the cases regulated in the Residence Act, a foreigner can seek or extend a residence permit in the Federal territory if:
>
> ...
>
> he...has a valid short-stay Schengen visa (Article 6 (1) (1) of the Aufenthaltsgesetz), inasmuch as the the conditions for a claim to the grant of a residence permit arise after entry, unless it is a claim under Sections 16, 17b or 18d of the Residence Act;
>
> ...

In your case, the job offer would be a condition allowing you to apply for a residence permit, and it will have arisen after your entry.

Comment: Isn't residence permit and work permit two different things? I think we can get residence permit easily for any good reason but, for a non-EU national, exit and re-entry is necessary. The agent also believes that it's not possible to get **work permit** after entry for a non-EU national.

Comment: @RexOverflow for the most part, the residence permit carries with it permission to work, but there are some exceptions.  See https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/aufenthalt/erwerbstaetigkeit/beschaeftigung/artikel.599046.en.php.  I would say, if you get the job offer, go down to the *Ausländerbehörde* and see if you can get your permit.  If you can, cancel the appointment in your home country.  If you can't, go back and attend the appointment.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try that!